# Git remove sequence of commits on a single branch permanently

Tags: git

I have a private github repo, used by only a few developers, and I accidentally committed a file containing password/sensitive data and pushed it a few commits back on a branch named develop.

I'm confident no other developers have made changes and am okay to rewrite history for these last few commits. The develop branch has not been merged into any other branches.

What is the correct way I can rollback to a particular commit that did not contain any history of the password/sensitive data and permanently delete the subsequent commits (so that the password/sensitive data is not in the history).

I have a copy and can easily handle copying back over code changes since the last known good commit. Note that it is about 3 commits back (each pushed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use (interactive) rebase.

1. Checkout the branch
2. Start interactive rebase, e.g. for last 3 commits: `git rebase -i head~3`
3. A file pops up*, those are the 3 commits. You could edit a commit, our entirely remove it.
   Example:

   ```
   pick ae1333333 commit1
   pick ae1333442 commit2
   pick ae1334477 commit3

   # Rebase be8b6221ee..170e76c22 onto be8b622ee (3 commands)
   #
   # Commands:
   # p, pick = use commit
   # r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
   # e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
   # s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
   # f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
   # x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
   # d, drop = remove commit
   #
   # These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
   #
   # If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
   #
   # However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
   #
   # Note that empty commits are commented out
   ```
4. Save and close the file.
5. This is indeed rewriting history, so you need a force push: `git push --force-with-lease`

   - You could also use `git push --force`, but `force-with-lease` is a safer one.

*: or showing inline in the console, depending of your configured text editor in git.

Comment: I think is exactly what I want to do, can I confirm all commits prior to ones I am removing will be intact. Also out of interest, I have a pull request in github with some comments (all prior to the commit in question), would it have any odd effects on the pull request/comments?

Comment: "can I confirm all commits prior to ones I am removing will be intact", What do you mean with this? "would it have any odd effects on the pull request/comments?" this works well with github PRs. There are some really small strange side-effects, e.g. notifications (for that PR) to others could be a bit unclear. Anyway, nothing breaks :)

Comment: It worked! looks like the history is gone, queue sigh of relief!